# Python Selenium Question: Right Mouse Button Click and Drag?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

**Update #2 (09/27/2020):**

Problem solved.

It turned out that the repeated action was caused by a bug in "reset_action" method from "ActionChains": [github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6837](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6837). If you are using Selenium 3.141.59 (latest version by now), you may find the above link helpful. According to the authors, the bug has been closed and (an update) "will be in the next release."

Finally, in the absence of a new release, my approach to this issue is to queue up all actions and use "perform()" only once at the end of my test. This means that you don't have to modify the selenium module. For example:

```
element_1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav")
element_2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element_1)
right_mouse_drag_by(100, 100, element_2)
actions.perform()
```

Hope this helps.

**Update #1 (09/27/2020):**

After taking a closer look at how selenium actually triggers the actions, I modified my helper function as shown below. Surprisingly, it worked.

However, something weird also happened: whichever action-chains method called right before the helper function got repeated. Any idea how this happened?

**Original Post:**

So here's the thing: selenium is amazing, but the project I am currently working on requires me to test a right-mouse-click-and-drag action on a web canvas. Selenium hasn't included this in its ActionChains module, since it is a rare case for most web-page testers.

Now, my idea is to create a helper function in my test file to perform this action. My search has lead me to the "pointer_actions" module in selenium in which the following class is available:

```
class PointerActions(Interaction):

    def __init__(self, source=None):
        if source is None:
            source = PointerInput(interaction.POINTER_MOUSE, "mouse")
        self.source = source
        super(PointerActions, self).__init__(source)

    def pointer_down(self, button=MouseButton.LEFT):
        self._button_action("create_pointer_down", button=button)

    def pointer_up(self, button=MouseButton.LEFT):
        self._button_action("create_pointer_up", button=button)

    def move_to(self, element, x=None, y=None):
        if not isinstance(element, WebElement):
            raise AttributeError("move_to requires a WebElement")
        if x is not None or y is not None:
            el_rect = element.rect
            left_offset = el_rect['width'] / 2
            top_offset = el_rect['height'] / 2
            left = -left_offset + (x or 0)
            top = -top_offset + (y or 0)
        else:
            left = 0
            top = 0
        self.source.create_pointer_move(origin=element, x=int(left), y=int(top))
        return self

    def move_by(self, x, y):
        self.source.create_pointer_move(origin=interaction.POINTER, x=int(x), y=int(y))
        return self

    def move_to_location(self, x, y):
        self.source.create_pointer_move(origin='viewport', x=int(x), y=int(y))
        return self

    def click(self, element=None):
        if element:
            self.move_to(element)
        self.pointer_down(MouseButton.LEFT)
        self.pointer_up(MouseButton.LEFT)
        return self

    def context_click(self, element=None):
        if element:
            self.move_to(element)
        self.pointer_down(MouseButton.RIGHT)
        self.pointer_up(MouseButton.RIGHT)
        return self

    def click_and_hold(self, element=None):
        if element:
            self.move_to(element)
        self.pointer_down()
        return self

    def release(self):
        self.pointer_up()
        return self

    def double_click(self, element=None):
        if element:
            self.move_to(element)
        self.click()
        self.click()

    def pause(self, duration=0):
        self.source.create_pause(duration)
        return self

    def _button_action(self, action, button=MouseButton.LEFT):
        meth = getattr(self.source, action)
        meth(button)
        return self
```

And my helper function is:

```
Act = ActionChains(browser)

# helpers
def right_mouse_drag_by(xoffset, yoffset, on_element=None):
    if on_element:
        Act.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to(on_element)
        return right_mouse_drag_by(xoffset, yoffset)
    else:
        Act.w3c_actions.clear_actions()
        Act.w3c_actions.pointer_action.pointer_down(MouseButton.RIGHT)
        Act.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_by(xoffset, yoffset)
        Act.w3c_actions.pointer_action.pointer_up(MouseButton.RIGHT)
        Act.w3c_actions.perform()
```

In short, the automation result is that, while pointer_down, pointer_up, and _button_action methods have taken the parameter "MouseButton.RIGHT", what's happening on screen is that my pointer is still performing left clicks when the helper function is called.

I looked up on StackOverflow and there was a similar question years ago which was never solved?

I'd really appreciate any suggestions or ideas.

Comment: [does](https://www.codementor.io/@pravallikabandaru/python-selenium-all-mouse-actions-using-actionchains-15tj5znvkv) this help you?

Comment: thank u but not really :)